# Does `echo -n | ...` send an EOF to the pipe?

Tags: shell, pipe, cat, file-descriptors, stdin

Does `echo -n | ...` send an EOF to the pipe? I.e.,

```
echo -n | sth
```

Will `sth` recieve an EOF on its stdin?

Comment: please note that : 1) you should replace `echo -n "something"` (shell dependant, and OS dependent) with : `printf "%s" "something"` (the portable way. )  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/27616 :  And 2) if you intend to pipe to another command, if that command expect a TEXT, a (last) line without a terminating "\n" is often not considered valid and will be discarded...  ex:   `printf "a\nb\nc\n" | wc -l` # **3 lines**, 3 words, 6 chars    `printf "a\nb\nc" | wc`  # **2 lines**, 3 words, 5 chars! , ie wc -l doesn't count the last line, even though it has characters on it!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk of "sending" or "receiving" end-of-file.  It's a condition, not some kind of data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no EOF that is represented as data in a file or stream. It is merely a status associated with the file descriptor.

When the echo terminates (which will be almost immediately), the write end of the pipe is closed.

The next time `sth` reads (assuming it has read all data previously written to the file) the pipe status changes to EOF and the read issued by `sth` returns with the EOF condition. The process can continue with any processing it requires, it just cannot read any more from the pipe.

Comment: “it just cannot read any more from the pipe” — that's true here, but it wouldn't be the case with a named pipe. With a named pipe, the reader could continue reading and would receive data if another process opens the named pipe for writing and writes to it.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Agreed -- I answered the question on the basis of a shell simple anonymous pipe. I believe a construct like `{ echo; sleep 5; echo bar; } | cat` lets all three processes inherit the pipe fd for writing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A program that reads from a pipe sees an end-of-file on the pipe when the program that writes to the pipe closes the writing end. More precisely, the end-of-file event happens when the last file descriptor that was open on the pipe gets closed. Ways to close a file descriptor include explicit closing and a process exiting.

Here there's just one process writing to the pipe and running `echo -n`, which depending on the shell either writes `-n` and a newline, or nothing. When that process has finished writing and exits, the writing end of the pipe is closed, so `sth` sees EOF on the pipe. (It's also possible that the shell runs the left-hand side of the pipe without forking, in which case the shell closes the pipe explicitly when it's done writing: this optimization doesn't make any difference to the right-hand side of the pipe.)